# printing 2-d character array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I want to create and print 2-D char array in C, which i will eventually use as an input in function "execvp()" for execute and development of a shell. When i execute the code i take this as an output and not the whole array.
 What is the problem?

In this part if the code i present only the part which i try to initialize the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i,j;
char **cmd[4][3] = {
        {"ls", "-l",NULL},
        {"grep", "test.c", NULL},
        {"wc", NULL},
        {"sort", "-r", NULL}
};

for(i=1;i<5;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       printf("%s\n",cmd[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
grep
test.c
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: --> `char *cmd[4][3] = {`, --> `for(i=0;i<4;i++)`, --> `for(j=0; cmd[i][j] && j<3;j++)`

Comment: Your compiler should give errors or warnings for the line `char **cmd`...  This is actually an error, although for historical reasons some compilers say "warning". Warnings should be treated as errors unless you completely understand the situation and know that it is not an error.  If your compiler didn't say anything, figure out how to invoke it in standard mode, or use a different compiler.

Comment: So the first problem was the incorrect indexes of loop and the check for NULL pointer.
The second one was the definition of *cmd[4][3] instead of **cmd[4][3]. 
Now for the next part of my work i will use the *cmd as an input for execvp().

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Why do you have `for(i=1;i<5;i++)` if you have only **4** rows?
Should it be

`printf("%s\n",cmd[i-1][j]);`

or

`for(i=0;i<4;i++)`

?

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2 dimensional array of pointers to char. So the definition for `cmd` should be:

```
char *cmd[4][3] = {...
```

The for loop has incorrect indexes. `for(i=1;i<5;i++)` should loop from 0 to 4.

And you should check before trying to print NULL pointers, which definitely exist in the array:

```
if( cmd[i][j] )
    printf("%s\n",cmd[i][j]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following program should give you an Idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(char **array,long unsigned int numWords){
    printf("\n");
    printf("Inside printArray:\n");
    long unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;i<numWords;i++){
            printf("%s\n",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
    long unsigned int numWords,i;
    char **array;

    printf("Introduce how many words do you want:> ");
    if((scanf("%lu", &numWords)) != 1){
        printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numWords * numWords);

    if (array == NULL)    {
        exit(2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
         array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
        printf("Enter your word number %lu:> ", i + 1);
        if((scanf("%s", array[i])) != 1){
            printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
            exit(3);
        }
    }

    printf("Inside Main:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
        printf("%s \n", array[i]);
    }

    printArray(array,numWords);

    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
         free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Inside Main:
Michael 
Jackson 

Inside printArray:
Michael
Jackson
```

EDIT:

based on your question, the following program does what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i,j;

    char *array[4][3] = {
        {"A", "B", "C"},
        {"D", "E", "F"},
        {"G", "H", "I"},
        {"J", "K", "L"},
    };


    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%s ", array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L
```